# Read application/pdf from Request Body - .NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, itext7

I am submitting a PDF file to my .NET CORE back-end.
The PDF was created using iText 7. I have added to the page few paragraphs and a `PdfButtonFormField` button with the following action

```
button.SetAction(PdfAction.CreateSubmitForm("http://localhost:4200/api/PdfSign/UploadPdfForSign", null, PdfAction.SUBMIT_PDF));
```

My endpoint gets the request. It looks like the request body has the binary data of the file but I have no idea how to read it.

Any help will be much appreciated!

** EDIT **
The goal is to get a PDF and sign it using iText.
The flow is - I am creating a PDF, adding the button to it and sends it to my customer. They do whatever they do on the PDF and send it back using the button from within the PDF.
I then want to read the details in my back end and sign it.
Hope this clears things.

Thank you,
Yaniv

Comment: How did you submit using jquery or any frontend js framework?

Comment: Could you please post more details codes about how you submit the PDF to action? Do you mean you want to save the PDF file after submitted?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I wrote, I have created the PDF using iText and added a button, using the code above. From what I can tell, the code uses a POST to the URL listed there.